# getting the local time dynamically

Tags: php

How can we know the time of a place from where a person logs in, a particular web application.

I and developing an internal management system for a huge business house in php. The business house has its branches located all over the world. I have to ensure that when an employee logs in to the application he or she can see the LOCAL TIME. This has to be dynamic. Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getTime.asp

Comment: @Nick : This is php and not javascript !

Comment: Davood, you need to query the client to figure out what their clock is set to, unless you want to keep records of which employees are in which timezones.

Comment: It's Possible that time of computer is not exactly set, any way, i think change Timezone is better way

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware, there is no "magic function" that will allow you to retrieve a user's local time through PHP, but a couple options you might consider are:

- Using javascript/AJAX to get the local time from the browser and pass it into your application (you could even store it in a database so that you only need to make the call once, if you'd like)
- Using a geolocation service to look up a user's (approximate) location based on their IP and estimate local time zone from that. If you choose this route, be aware that IP geoloc is pretty much "best guess" technology and can be wildly inaccurate
- You also might consider simply asking the user what their preferred time zone is. It's not the fanciest method, but it's guaranteed to be right (within a margin of error allowing for user choice)

Comment: Last point might be best as no guarantee that users devices have correct time, except that user could have traversed TZs on business trips - so mixture of solutions might be best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use from [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) php built-In function

Comment: Yeah sure, but how does he know what zone to set it to? For example, one client logs on from India, another from Belgium... what does the code look like? See @Problematic's answer...